# adding raw text to a SOAP header

Tags: java, soap, text, header

In Java, I need to add a SOAP header containing authentication data for a client-side SOAP request to a 3rd party web service that I have no control over.  I have set up a SOAPHandler, and am monitoring the actual code sent to the server-side to see what is going on.  The authentication is not working.

What I precisely need is:

```
<soap12:Header>
    <AuthenticationHeader xmlns="http://abc.xyz.com/">
      <UserName>uname</UserName>
      <Password>pwd</Password>
    </AuthenticationHeader>
  </soap12:Header>
```

I can create the `AuthenticationHeader` element and add it with the `SOAPHeader.addHeaderElement` method without issue, but I can't get the username and password content added properly.  What I can get from using the various commands to set the text for a SOAPElement (setValue, setTextContent, addTextNode), and then using `SOAPHeaderElement.addChildElement` is

```
<soap12:Header>
        <AuthenticationHeader xmlns="http://abc.xyz.com/">
          <UserName xmlns="">uname</UserName>
          <Password xmlns="">pwd</Password>
        </AuthenticationHeader>
      </soap12:Header>
```

The server side can't cope with the extra `xmlns=""` that all the commands I have tried seem to add to the UserName and Password tag names.

If I try to construct a string and add that text directly to the `AutheticationHeader` element, the < and > characters are escaped.  I've also tried CDATA tags...that prevents escaping of the < and > characters, but the server still doesn't like it.

I found a solution constructing a `Document` to hold the raw text (which prevents escaping the characters), and then adding that, but unfortunately, it seems that `Document` can only be added to the SOAP body, not the SOAP header.

Does anyone have any suggestions how to overcome this?  The server people are programming in .NET, not Java, so they aren't able to help.

I am getting the proper response back from the server, with all off the correct SOAP output tags, but the error message contained in the  tag is "Can't Authenticate".

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code will generate the correct `Authentication` Header that you would like to generate.

```
SOAPHeader header = request.getSOAPHeader();

Document doc = header.getOwnerDocument();

Element el1 = doc.createElementNS("http://abc.xyz.com/","UserName");
el1.setTextContent("MyName");

Element el2 = doc.createElementNS("http://abc.xyz.com/","Password");
el2.setTextContent("pass******");

Element el0 = doc.createElementNS("http://abc.xyz.com/", "AuthenticationHeader");

el0.appendChild(el1);
el0.appendChild(el2);
header.appendChild(el0);
```